# Issue converting nested loops to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I'm struggling to convert the following nested loops, with conditions to a more readable LINQ statement.

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> testClassPageObjects = FindPageObjects();
T newControl = default(T);

Parallel.ForEach(testClassPageObjects, (pageObject,state) =>
{              
    Type pageObjectType = pageObject.PropertyType;
    var pageObjectControls = pageObjectType.GetFields();

    foreach (var control in pageObjectControls.Where(control => control.FieldType == typeof(T)))
    {
        if (control.Name == fieldNameNoSpaces)
        {
            var findsByAttribute = (FindsByAttribute) control.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(FindsByAttribute));
            newControl = (T) control
                .FieldType
                .GetConstructor(new[] {typeof(IWebDriver), typeof(By)})
                .Invoke(new object[] {driver, findsByAttribute.Locator});

            state.Break();
        }
    }              
});
```

Everything before and including the if statement I would like in a LINQ statement if possible. The statement should return the first match. The use of Parallel.ForEach and foreach need not be relevant in this case.

Many thanks,

Comment: You can start by adding `&& control.Name == fieldNameNoSpaces` to your `Where()` condition. I don't know why you'd have half the conditions in one place and the rest in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it would look something like this. Not sure this is more readable honestly.

```
T control = FindPageObjects
            .SelectMany
                (
                    pageObject => 
                    pageObject.PropertyType.GetFields()
                )
            .OfType<T>()
            .Where
                (
                    control =>
                    control.FieldType == typeof(T) && 
                    control.Name == fieldNameNoSpaces
                )
            .Select
                (    
                    selectedControl =>
                    selectedControl.FieldType
                    .GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(IWebDriver), typeof(By)})
                    .Invoke
                        (
                            new object[]
                            {
                                driver, 
                               ((FindsByAttribute)(selectedControl.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(FindsByAttribute)))).Locator
                            }
                        )
                )
            .OfType<T>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Explanation:

**SelectMany** allows you to iterate over a set within a set (controls within the page objects)

**OfType** makes sure you are only looking at controls of type T, and eliminates the need to cast it later.

**Where** checks the FieldType and Name.

**Select** uses reflection to instantiate a new T based on the FieldType of the control.

**OfType** is necessary a second time to cast the result of the constructor invocation to T.

**FirstOrDefault** means that the LINQ will run this for the first record it finds, and if it doesn't find any it'll just return null. This corresponds to the `Break` in your original code.

By the way, if you want parallelism, you could simply add [AsParallel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413237(v=vs.110).aspx), although I'm not sure how much of an improvement that would make.

Comment: Thanks. Whilst I didn't end up performing the entire action in LINQ like your suggestion, it did provide me with what I needed.

Comment: I wouldn't normally write something like this in one statement, but I thought it would be a fun challenge. Maybe not the right approach for production code.